# Will Google Documents List API be deprecated?

Tags: google-drive-api

Are there any plans to deprecate [Google Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) in nearest future?

I am using it in my utility to backup files to Google Drive. Does it make sense for me to switch to [Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/) instead, for the long term support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely move to the Drive SDK. It replaces almost all the functionality of the Documents List API, and adds some, while being much nicer to use.

Comment: Yes, it contains a regular API which you cna use form anywhere.